# Salvando arquivos em txt com c++

Tags: c++, sistema-de-arquivos, txt

Estou tentando criar um programa que salva os dados armazenados com hash em 4 arquivos txt diferentes, conforme for o índice do hash ele escolhe o arquivo que deve salvar.

exemplo:

```
hash índice 0 = txt_0.txt
hash índice 1 = txt_1.txt
hash índice 2 = txt_2.txt
hash índice 3 = txt_3.txt
```

Então criei um for que percorre tudo a minha lista, e criei um literator para poder resgatar os dados da lista e salvar no txt, o problema e que ele só salva se eu cadastro um depois salvo, se cadastro 2 ele só salva o ultimo cadastrado.

```
void func_arquivo::cria_arquivo(int código, int idade, string nome, int     indice){
ofstream arquivo;
for(int i=0;i<TAM;i++){
    char nome_arquivo[FILENAME_MAX];//usado para que a função consiga escrever todos os nomes dentro do char se nao ele nao comporta
    sprintf(nome_arquivo, "Data-%d.txt",i);//função que realiza conversao de inteiros para char
    arquivo.open(nome_arquivo, ios::app);

    if(indice == i){
        arquivo << codigo << "\t" << idade << "\t" <<  nome << "\n";
    }
    arquivo.close();
 }
}
```

Este é o código que escreve no txt.

Oque sera que acontece?

Já estou meio perdido com isso.

Comment: Se você vai criar um arquivo de acordo com o `indice`, o `for` talvez seja desnecessário, testei o teu código aqui e parece funcionar...

Comment: Olá Origado por tentar ajudar mas na verdade estava faltando um for por isso só gravava o ultimo elemento inserido ele não lia a lista inteira apenas o ultimo valor.

Comment: Mas que lista é essa? outra coisa, como você está chamando `cria_arquivo`?